# Set Image context to sub view for ScreenShot using Swift

Tags: swift

I want to capture an image (screenshot) which is in a view that is part of a Stack View (here is is **ResultsView**).  Because I'm using the stack view to reposition the two views, I need to use the ResultsView view to capture the image (i.e. I cannot use the geography on the screen).

where I ended up was either the whole or part, using some screen position:

```
    // full screen shot
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    //print("ScreenShot")
    //UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(sourceImage!, nil, nil, nil)

    // partial screen shot
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    sourceImage?.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 275))
    let croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    print("Partial ScreenShot")
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(croppedImage!, nil, nil, nil)
```

Swift 4

[image: view hierarchy]

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question...

```
@IBAction func screenShot(_ sender: RoundButton) {
    sender.pulsate()
    makeSystemSound(sound: 1108)  // camera shutter
    //screenshot with cropping to CGRect from a view
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let sourceImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    let captureFrame = view.convert(ResultsView.frame, from:self.view)
    let newImage = crop(image: sourceImage!, cropRect: captureFrame)
    print("Partial ScreenShot")
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage!, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

and the function:

```
func crop(image: UIImage, cropRect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cropRect.size, false, image.scale)
    let origin = CGPoint(x: cropRect.origin.x * CGFloat(-1), y: cropRect.origin.y * CGFloat(-1))
    image.draw(at: origin)
    let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return result
}
```